# Subgroup of motions without a translation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, rigid-transformation

Let $G \subset M$ be the smallest subgroup of rigid transformations in $\mathbb R^2$ containing a rotation of $1$ radian about $(0,0)$ (call this element $m_1$) and a rotation of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ radians fixing $(1,0)$ (call this $m_2$).

I suspect that $G$ contains no translation, since I don't see how we can apply $m_1$ and $m_2$ finitely many times and somehow remove the $1$ radian.

Yet Artin's *Algebra* seems to insist otherwise.  An exercise in the chapter about symmetry asks us to prove that a subgroup of rigid motions in $\mathbb R^2$ containing rotations that fix $2$ separate points contains a translation.

So who is right?

Comment: Commutator of $m_1$ and $m_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angles of rotation add: that is, if you do $m_1$ first and then $m_2$, you will have a total rotation about *some* point of $1+\pi/4$. From an advanced standpoint, there’s a map from the group of rigid motions of the plane to the circle group that’s a homomorphism. Now all you need to do is get the total rotation equal to zero, say by doing $m_1\circ m_2\circ m_1^{-1}\circ m_2^{-1}$. This is a rigid motion, certainly not identity, with rotation zero. So, a translation.

Answer (score 3):

Call the two transformations $a$ and $b$. Then conjugating, $b^{-1}ab$ is a rotation of 1 radian about a new point $(1-1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{2})$ distinct from the first two. Call this conjugate $c$.

Then $bc^{-1}$ is a translation along the line perpendicular to their two fixed points, like waddling along with a board glued on your feet.

Comment: I do indeed. It's hard to type right with a chunk of hardwood on your heels.... *thud* *thud*

Comment: But if $c=b^{-1}ab$, then $c^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}b$, and $bc^{-1}=a^{-1}b$, isn’t that right?

Comment: Someone had a deleted comment; my post should say $ac^{-1}$.

Comment: It should be possible to edit your own answer, @Brian Rushton.